# grep based on condition then sed

Tags: linux, sed, command-line, grep

I have a file and I want to write a command that deletes the block based on the word.
If I want to delete `sara@example.com` the deletion start from the word `user` to `}` character.

file:

```
user "sara" {
  first_name           = "Sara"
  login                = "sara@example.com"

}

user "john_smith" {
  first_name           = "John"
  login                = "john_smith@example.com"
  last_name            = "Smith"

}
```

I am a beginner at sed and grep commands

I would appreciate it if someone help!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little difficult to get the results you're looking for using just grep and sed. If you're able to use perl, though, this should work:

```sh
# cat test.txt
user "sara" {
  first_name           = "Sara"
  login                = "sara@example.com"

}

user "john_smith" {
  first_name           = "John"
  login                = "john_smith@example.com"
  last_name            = "Smith"

}

user "sara" {
  first_name           = "Sara"
  login                = "sara@example.com"

}

user "john_doe" {
  first_name           = "John"
  login                = "john_doe@example.com"
  last_name            = "Doe"
}
# perl -pe 'BEGIN {$/ = "}"} undef $_ if /sara\@example.com/' test.txt


user "john_smith" {
  first_name           = "John"
  login                = "john_smith@example.com"
  last_name            = "Smith"

}

user "john_doe" {
  first_name           = "John"
  login                = "john_doe@example.com"
  last_name            = "Doe"
}
```

Commented code below:

```perl
# Run with the -p flag to, by default, print every line in the file being read
BEGIN {
    # Set the INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR variable to a closing curly brace
    # This causes Perl to treat each block as a separate "line"
    $/ = "}";
}
# If the current block contains "sara@example.com", don't print anything.
# Note that the ampersand (@) character has to be escaped with a backslash as seen below
undef $_ if /sara\@example.com/;
```

Comment: Your command just print everything on the file not the block only :(

Comment: Just to confirm, you ran the command `perl -pe 'BEGIN {$/ = "}"} undef $_ if /sara\@example.com/' <FILENAME>`, correct? I included the output this command produces on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/user/{:a;/}/!{N;ba};/sara@example\.com/d}' file
```

Gather up lines starting with a line that contains `user` and ending when another (or the same) line contains `}`.

If the collection contains the string `sara@example.com`, then delete those lines.

Answer (score 0):

When your data is has `user` in the first column and is without `}` this might work:

```
sed -rz 's/(^|\n)user[^}]*sara@example.com[^}]*}//' file
```

Option `-z` disables to line-orientation of `sed`, a little bit cheating.
With `[^}]*` you wil be matching a string without a `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you think you need sed AND grep, you should almost certainly be using awk instead. Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and based on one possible interpretation of your requirements:

```
$  awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="}\n"} !/sara@example.com/' file

user "john_smith" {
  first_name           = "John"
  login                = "john_smith@example.com"
  last_name            = "Smith"

}
```